# Xamarin xaml string formatting with placeholder

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

we use rex files in our application , I have string that in the resource file that is like that

*You will need {0} per month to meet your payment requirements.*

Myresourcstring=x:Static i18N:Resources.MonthlyPaymentRequirement

in Xaml
what should my label Text look like,:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Amount, StringFormat="{x:Static i18N:Resources.MonthlyPaymentRequirement}"/>
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is "Path=", check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#examples)

```
<Label Text="{Binding Path=Amount, StringFormat={x:Static i18N:Resources.MonthlyPaymentRequirement}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the link , I will look at it now, tried your suggestions but for some reason the text didnt show , missing the obvious?

Comment: Edited. Sorry for my carelessness with the wrong closing tag. Double quote for the whole text value, and no double quote for StringFormat when using i18n resources.